# How values are passed in module call

Tags: magento-1.9, custom-options

I used a module for category slider. To call this in static block I used below the line.

```
{{block type="vsourz_catproduct/productslider" category_id="6" title="Product Slider" template="vsourz/products/productslider.phtml" product_count="12"}}
```

Everything is working perfect, actually, i want to learn how values are passed as **category_id="6"** or **title="Product Slider"** in above call.

How to achieve this if I want to make my own modules.

There is function in block

```
<?php
class Vsourz_Catproduct_Block_Productslider extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract{
    public function getProducts(){
        --> $catId = $this->getCategoryId();
        $prodCnt = $this->getProductCount();
        $_productCollection = Mage::getModel("vsourz_catproduct/productslider")->getItemCollection($catId,$prodCnt);
        return $_productCollection;
    }
}
```

Is this function get the category_id.
Kindly suggest.

Comment: yes. when you assign `category_id="6"` and `product_count="12"`  these value are set on block by setter method and in block class you can get using getter method

Comment: so if there is a label like  some_id then in block I can get the value like  $catId = $this->getSomeId();

Comment: correct  ........

Comment: I will surely try this thank you. Is there any link from which I can learn about creating these type of modules or extension.